# Can I create a select list with a MVC3 helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC3. I would like to create a select list / dropdown that will allow me to select between 2-3 things. I only want to be able to select the one from a list. Is there an easy way to do this with a helper.

Mary Jean

Here's my idea.

```
The helper will select from choices:

1 answer
2 answers
3 answers
```

and store the result in task_type variable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the [`DropDownListFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor.aspx) helper. I would start by defining a view model:

```
public class AnswersViewModel
{
    public string SelectedAnswer { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Answers
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "1 answer" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "2 answers" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "3 answers" },
            };
        }
    }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new AnswersViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(AnswersViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and finally a strongly typed view:

```
@model AnswersViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedAnswer,
        new SelectList(Model.Answers, "Value", "Text")
    )
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Now when the user submits the form the Index POST action will be invoked and the `SelectedAnswer` property of the view model will be automatically populated with the user selection from the dropdown.

Comment: Wow Darin, your answer is really good. I can learn a lot from you. Thanks very much !!

Comment: One question. It says SelectListItem could not be found. Do I need to define that class?

Comment: @MaryJean, no, you need to import the namespace where this class is defined: `using System.Web.Mvc`.